# Should extensive edits reset vote counts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Poorly written question is voted into oblivion. Later extensive edits improve the quality, yet if voted users don't bother to revisit the votes the improved question remains unseen.

A solution: Add feature 'reset votes'. Maybe this could be voted upon? Similarly as closing/opening.

Less invasive way: 'send mail to voters to please re-visit this topic for consideration'

Comment: This isn't something we could do here at skeptics alone, so [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 5):

> A solution: Add feature 'reset votes'. Maybe this could be voted upon? Similarly as closing/opening.

This happens — manually. The downvotes are still there, of course, but they are canceled out by people who upvote. I've seen this happen here with my own eyes; one question was quickly downvoted to -5, got salvaged by moderator edits, and ended up at a final score of +3 (+10/-7). Questions like that show that "oblivion" isn't so hard to get out of. And that question, to my knowledge, didn't get any help on Meta or in chat.

> Less invasive way: 'send mail to voters to please re-visit this topic for consideration'

This exists, but opt-in only. Just click on "follow".

Comment: I suspect this meta-question was triggered by [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/55648/) which I recently bountied. From memory, it had a score of about minus 6-10, I edited it, but the edit never appeared on the front page (presumably due to the score). I eventually put a bounty on it to try to give it enough visibility to counteract the downvotes [hoping my own evaluation of the question's quality was shared by the community]. So, I am not convinced your proposal actually works with seriously downvoted questions.

Comment: @Oddthinking it is. I did not wish to piggyback on anyone. Proposal should  stands on it's own. Apparently majority doesn't care for it.

Comment: @pinegulf: Understood; I think you did the right thing. I am just using that question as an anecdote to support that there is a need for something like this feature.

Answer (score 0):

No they shouldn't because that would make it to easy for someone to get rid of the results of a bad question.

Comment: But the question wouldn't be bad anymore after the editing?

Comment: @pinegulf Maybe it is and maybe it isn't. Just because it has had a large revision doesn't mean that the issues have been fixed and people who downvoted it might still think it needs to be downvoted. No edit or review process should be able to remove someone else's vote. It is up to each induvial voter to decide what should happen to the vote. Not to mention people would be more willing to post bad questions/answers if they know they could get the votes removed by changing the post.

Comment: @pinegulf How do you know the edit made the question no longer bad?

Comment: @ComicSansStrikephim By default, I don't. Assumption is that if some-one spends a lot of time trying to improving a question it would get better.

Comment: @pinegulf And that is a bad assumption to make. Someone could have spent a lot of time just fixing the grammar of a question in order to help others understand it better but overall it is the same question with the same problems.

Comment: True, they might. Just as well they might improve the question a lot. Currently situation is that audience does not bother to re-visit after voting. Why bother trying to improve if there is no effect?

Comment: @pinegulf That does not justify resetting the votes on a question.